# Как Urho3D запускается на телефоне?

Tags: javascript, html, lua

Зашол на этот сайт https://urho3d.io/samples/

И запустил пару примеров с телефона.
Запускается и работает.

[image] [image]

вот хочу узнать как это работает.

В случае с станционарным компьютером там всë понятно(у меня всë прекрасно работает).

А тут так и не понял, посмотрел хтмл файл и увидел такую строчку `src=01_HelloWorld.js><`

А ведь нигде не указано что движок работает на js (джава скрипт), as (angel script) я так открыть ссылку не смог так как в телефоне и интернете не нашëл подходящей читалки, lua на телефоне так и не открылся (выпрыгивает ошибка что нету луа, после нажатия , черный экран)

[image]

Comment: «В случае с станционарным компьютером там всë понятно» — ну а почему на телефоне должно что-то принципиально отличаться?)

Comment: Ну а то, как он работает в браузере, это уже старая тема — [emscripten](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten) и [WebAssembly](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly). Если вы поковыряетесь в скачиваемых `*.wasm` файлах, то, помимо прочего, найдёте там упоминания и AngelScript тоже

Comment: Если вы вдруг как-то умудрились это пропустить, в браузере уже запускали и [Unreal Tournament](https://icculus.org/ut99-emscripten/), и [Doom 3](http://www.continuation-labs.com/projects/d3wasm/), и даже целый [Windows 95](https://archive.org/details/win95_in_dosbox)